# Docusign access envelopes of user who is cc'ed on envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

On Sandbox Docusion envelope creation , User 1 , sends envelope  to user 3 and cc'ng user 2 .

Using credentials of user 2 , will I be able to get the envelopes on which i am cc'ed.

Is this possible ?
Edit- @CodingDwag -Envelope options as you asked in comments

```
 DateTime fromDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(-1);
    string fromDateStr = fromDate.ToString("o");
    // set a filter for the envelopes we want returned using the fromDate 
    return _EnvelopeOptions = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions()
    {
        fromDate = fromDateStr,
        toDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"),
        status = "completed"
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a CCed user2 can access the envelope.

Comment: I am using this -   EnvelopesInformation envelopes = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(_accountId, _EnvelopeOptions);  Envelope envInfo = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(_accountId, env.EnvelopeId); and passing accId of user2 , But not able to get those contracts on which I am cc'ed

Comment: Missed a crucial thing . I am on Sandbox env. I think on sandbox , we cannot link users and avail this feature , cc'ed users access is applicable on production only. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Sandbox should have all the features of DocuSign. https://www.docusign.com/company/terms-and-conditions/sandbox

Comment: What are the _EnvelopeOptions you are passing? Can you please update your question with your code.

Comment: I checked it, listStatusChanges is not returning the envelope which is CCed to me and I think listStatusChanges will list only those envelopes which are sent by my account. Whereas in this case I am CCed in an envelope, I can find the CCed envelope using below endpoint `GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/completed?from_date=2017-09-07`, reference https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/search/

Comment: Thanks @AmitKBist for the clarifications. So what i hae proposed is that since we have a user which has admin rights on the company Docusign non sandbox a/c , the admin user can fetch all the envelopes created by all the users under the Company Docusign a/c

Comment: Yes @ABDmaverick, an Admin can get all the envelopes, at that time you should use GET /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes?from_date=2017-09-13, this will return all the envelopes in the account in all the status. But it will not return the envelopes which are CCed to me from another account.

Comment: No @AmitKBist I Meant admin user can fetch all envelopes , even the ones not created by it ( those of other docusign users)

Comment: Yes it can fetch all the envelopes in the account